# Zend Framework 11.1: Form_Customer not found in

Tags: php, zend-framework, namespaces, zend-form

First of all, I know there are a few quite similar questions here on stackoverflow about that form problem but none of them could actually help me so I'm giving it a try myself. I've been stuck with this for the past 10 hours and I'm really desesperate right now.

So, let's start with my directory structure:

```
  gpos/
  ---- application/
       --- forms/
       ------- CustomerForm.php
       --- modules/
           --- default/
               --- controllers/
                   --- CustomerController.php
               --- views/
       --- Bootstrap.php
  ---- public/
  ---- library/
       --- Doctrine/
       --- GPos/
           --- Doctrine/
               --- ActiveEntity.php
           --- Models/
               --- Customer.php
```

As you can see, I'm using Zend's standard forms/ folder to store my forms and I'm also using Doctrine as DB manager.

---

So I've been trying to reach my `CustomerForm.php` from `CustomerController.php` but simply getting a not found error.

Here is the error I'm getting:
`Fatal error: Class 'Form_CustomerForm' not found in C:\wamp\www\GPos\gpos\application\modules\default\controllers\CustomerController.php on line 9`

`CustomerController.php:`

```
class CustomerController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function init() {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        $form = new Form_CustomerForm(); //line 9
        $form->setAction('/customer/index');
        $form->setMethod('post');
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
```

and `CustomerForm.php:`

```
class Form_CustomerForm extends Zend_Form {
    public function init() {
```

and finally `views/scripts/customer/submit.phtml:`

```
<h2>Customer</h2>
<p>To create blabla</p>

<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

---

I've been desesperately trying to add Form namespace to the autoloader but I learned today that it was already in thanks to Zend doing it for us. So... What am I doing wrong? I found tons of posts saying how to add resources and how to manage custom forms and I feel I'm doing exactly what's asked but it just won't work not matter what.

I'm afraid that it comes from somewhere else cause I've been trying to add different namespaces unsuccessfully too such as GPos_Doctrine for my ActiveEntity.php file in `library/GPos/Doctrine/` with:

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Application',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
    ));
    $autoloader->addResourceType('gpos', '/../../library/GPos', 'GPos');
    $autoloader->addResourceType('doctrine', '/../../library/GPos/Doctrine', 'GPos_Doctrine');

    return $autoloader;
}
```

This didn't work either. I'm quite unsure of the 'path' parameter (2nd param) but I saw in a tutorial that the path of eath resource type you add must be relative to autoloader's basePath, so I came up with these paths.

The only way I could make my GPos_Doctrine_ActiveEntity() work was by adding `autoloadernamespaces[] = "GPos_"` to application.ini. Adding `autoloadernamespaces[] = "Form_"`didn't work though... I really don't understand what's wrong with my resource types I'm adding.

Please note that I didn't use zf tools to build that project. I'm considering doing it if I don't find a way to make it all work correctly.

I've also tried to rename my form class to "Application_Form_CustomerForm" but didn't do any good either. I feel I've tried everything I could now. I'm just deseperate :(

Oh and by the way, the only work around I found at first is to put forms/ folder in my library, that worked. Don't understand why, but I don't want to use that hack. See, I'm doing this project as my IT Bachelor work graduation and I really shouldn't get into hacking things to make them work :P.

Thank you for anybody paying attention!

Comment: I should read before I post....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either add an bootstrap to the default module (which in turn sets the resourcetypes automaticly)

```
class Default_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload() {
        $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                    'namespace' => 'Default_',
                    'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default'));
        return $moduleLoader;
    }
}
```

or add this to your global bootstrap (extend it with your two custom resourcetypes):

```
public function _initDefaultResourceTypes() {
    $al = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/default/',
        'resourceTypes' => array(
            'dbtable' => array(
                'namespace' => 'Model_DbTable',
                'path'      => 'models/DbTable',
            ),
            'mappers' => array(
                'namespace' => 'Model_Mapper',
                'path'      => 'models/mappers',
            ),
            'form'    => array(
                'namespace' => 'Form',
                'path'      => 'forms',
            ),
            'model'   => array(
                'namespace' => 'Model',
                'path'      => 'models',
            ),
            'plugin'  => array(
                'namespace' => 'Plugin',
                'path'      => 'plugins',
            ),
            'service' => array(
                'namespace' => 'Service',
                'path'      => 'services',
            ),
            'viewhelper' => array(
                'namespace' => 'View_Helper',
                'path'      => 'views/helpers',
            ),
            'viewfilter' => array(
                'namespace' => 'View_Filter',
                'path'      => 'views/filters',
            )
          )
    ));
    $al->setDefaultResourceType('model');
}
```

take a look at this ZF 1 Skeleton for further info:
https://github.com/eddiejaoude/Zend-Framework--Doctrine-ORM--PHPUnit--Ant--Jenkins-CI--TDD-

Comment: Thank you! Moving forms/ to modules/default/ + adding your public function _initDefaultResourceTypes() stripped from resource types I didn't need made the trick. Thank you SO MUCH.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use modules but here what I do, which is very basic :

In /public/index.php, I add "/forms" to the include path :
(important part is the line with "forms" of course

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/forms'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

My form are then named :

```
class Default_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
```

Then I would do :

```
$form = new Default_Form_Login();
```

Comment: That worked too, thank you, but I prefer Rufinus' answer. Thanks for helping mate.